# condition for two different 'get' collection inside foreach loop in laravel blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have two `get` collections for - 1) availabletime and 2) bookingtime.

For available time -

```
$availabletimes= AvailableTime::where('available_day_id', $availabledayid)
                               ->get(['available_time']);
```

Example Output:

```
(3) [
     {available_time: "10:00:00"},
     {available_time: "12:00:00"},
     {available_time: "13:00:00"}
    ]
```

For booking time -

```
$bookingtimes = Appointment::where('specialist_id', $specialistid)
                           ->where('booking_date', '=', $date)
                           ->get(['booking_time']);
```

Example Output:

```
(2) [
     {booking_time: "10:00:00"},
     {booking_time: "13:00:00"}
    ]
```

I want to show all the available times in the blade file and check if `appointment_time` and `booking_time` are the same.

Inside blade file, I am trying like-

```
@foreach ($availabletimes as $index => $element)    
<p>{{ $element->available_time }} - 
   {{--here I want to check if booking time is equal to available time--}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pluck` to get time in array

```
$bookingtimes = Appointment::where('specialist_id', $specialistid)
                           ->where('booking_date', '=', $date)
                           ->pluck('booking_time')->toArray();
```

By this you'll get array of the times.

```
[0=>"10:00:00",1=>"13:00:00"];
```

Now you can use `in_array()` in `foreach`

```
@foreach ($availabletimes as $index => $element)    
<p>{{ $element->available_time }} - 
   @if(in_array($element->available_time,$bookingtimes)) 'time is available' @endif</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **pluck()** and **isset()**

```
$availabletimes= AvailableTime::where('available_day_id', $availabledayid)
                               ->get(['available_time']);

$bookingtimes = Appointment::where('specialist_id', $specialistid)
                           ->where('booking_date', '=', $date)
                           ->pluck('booking_time','booking_time')->toArray();

@foreach ($availabletimes as $index => $element)  
  @if(isset($bookingtimes[$element->available_time]))  
   <p>$element->available_time</p>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@foreach ($availabletimes as $index => $element)    
    <p>{{ $element->available_time }} - 
        @if(in_array($element->available_time,$booking_time))
          {{--not sure what you want in here--}}
        @endif
    </p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a simple `left join` between `bookings` and `appointments` on `booking_time` and `available_time` . This way you can completely avoid the in_array() check and simply loop over the result set in your blade file, as the unmatched rows will have `NULL` values in `available_time` column in your final result set.

**Query:**(double check with your table names)

```
$time_details = DB::table('bookings bks')
                ->leftJoin('appointments appt', 'appt.available_time', '=', 'bks.booking_time')
                ->select('bks.booking_time','appt.available_time')
                ->where('appt.available_day_id','=',$availabledayid)
                ->where('bks.specialist_id','=',$specialistid)
                ->where('bks.booking_date','=',$date)
                ->get();
```

**Blade file:**

```
@foreach ($time_details as $detail)    
   @if(empty($detail->available_time))
      <p>{{ $detail->available_time }} - is not available.</p>   
   @else
      <p>{{ $detail->available_time }} - is available.</p> 
   @endif
@endforeach
```